# What is com.apple.dasd.swapkills.plist?

Tags: video, iphone, plist

com.apple.dasd.swapkills.plist

Anyone know what this is? I've recently had police delete footage off my phone, am taking them to court. Can't get the videos back as I accidentally overwrote them when my iCloud backed up, but I have received the data back from Forensics (I sent my phone to them). I'm not a coder or anything but could use your brains trust to help me decipher some funny business. Some of it may be innocent, but the 3 days my phone was with the police there's definitely activity. I'm just trying to ascertain if some of it is useful for court. Cheers in advance! Jess

Comment: dasd = Duet Activity Scheduler Daemon, 

plist  = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list

Comment: Where are you seeing this filename? In a log message? Can you give us the whole message, or other context?

Comment: The 5 or so hours that the police were actively fiddling with my phone there is a lot of activity with various plist files. Does that mean anything to you? Here are some examples:

Answer (score 0):

> Duet Activity Scheduler (DAS) maintains a scored list of background
> activities which usually consists of more than seventy items.
> Periodically, it rescores each item in its list, according to various
> criteria such as whether it is now due to be performed, i.e. clock
> time is now within the time period in which Centralized Task
> Scheduling (CTS) calculated it should next be run.

There is an [article on eclecticlight](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/05/13/how-macos-runs-background-activities-1-from-within-an-app/) further explaining the processes
around macOS and background activities.